# Stub UUID using SINON with uuid version 9

Tags: javascript, testing, uuid, sinon

I'm updating NodeJS and dependencies versions and got a problem trying to update `uuid` from `v3.1.0` to `v9.0.0` on my tests.

This was working before the update, but not anymore.

```
sinon = require('sinon'),
uuid = require('uuid'),

before(async () => {
  uuidV4Stub = sinon.stub(uuid, 'v4').returns('RANDOM_ID');
});
```

I read the [uuid npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and found:

> As of uuid@7 this library now provides ECMAScript modules builds,
> which allow packagers   like Webpack and Rollup to do "tree-shaking"
> to remove dead code. Instead, use the import syntax:
>
> import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'; uuidv4(); ... or for CommonJS:
>
> const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid'); uuidv4();
>
> Default Export Removed

Is it still possible to stub it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Heyo,

I've been there when I tried to alter uuid library

take this example and let's see how to it goes with you:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const {v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid')

let uuidV4stub = null;

before(async () => {
uuidV4stub = sinon .stub(uuidv4, 'name').value(() => 'ANY_RANDOM_ID');
});
after(() => {
uuidV4stub.restore();
});
```

so here is the deal, grab that v4 thingy with some fancy de-structuring and call it `uuidv4` just to keep things slick. Old school stubbing isn't gonna cut it cause its a constant now, so switch it up and use `sinon.stub().value()` to swap it out and don't space out and forget to reset that `stub` after your tests or things might go sideways

Comment: Hi, Karam! What the `name` is supposed to be? As we are de-structuring the `v4` out of `uuid`. Waht I'm supposed to pass as argument for `stub()`? Thanks